# Fit Frame To Content after changing it's contents

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign

Ok, let's say I have this textFrame selected:

[image: starting point]

I want to apply this:

[image: Fit Frame To Content]

To get this expected result:

[image: wanted result]

With this code it's no problem:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var target = doc.selection[0];
target.fit(FitOptions.frameToContent);
```

But as soon as I set the content it goes wrong. Even if the content is the same to what it was.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var target = doc.selection[0]; 
target.contents = "0209 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit nam finibus ut justo at fermentum maecenas tincidun libero at aliquet finibus libero sem semper massa.";
target.fit(FitOptions.frameToContent);
```

Now I get 1 big line!:

[image: unwanted result]

Is this a bug, or do I need to trigger an update method or something?

Comment: (Untested) Add `target.recompose()` after setting the contents. Composing (i.e., breaking the text into lines) usually happens in the background; ID just may not have the time between your two function calls to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `target.recompose()` after setting the contents. Composing (i.e., breaking the text into lines) usually happens in the background; ID just may not have the time between your two function calls to do so.

It's not clear from the documentation *when* you need to explicitly call `recompose`, but as a rule of thumb you can assume interacting through a text `contents` property always needs it. The `contents` of a native InDesign text are translated from and to a Javascript string object, and thus loose all 'native' formatting, including any and all paragraph composition.

I just tried it with my trusty old CS4 and there it works without `recompose` as well, although that is not conclusive; InDesign just may have had 'the time' to do it in the background, with no other tasks running. So forcing it may still be a good idea.